# Can anyone help me with a error while working in angular?

Tags: angular

For my study I have to make a list of Campings and an button to insert new campings to the list. I'm very new to this. My book is based on an older version then I'm working with. This is what I have:

**campinginvoer.component.html:**

```
<label for="CampingNaam">Campingnaam</label>
<input type="text" id="CampingNaam" [(ngModule)]="InvoerCampingNaam">
<button> (click)="onCreateCamping()">Invoeren</button>
<!-- <app-camping [campingList]="campings"></app-camping> -->
```

**campinginvoer.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-camping-invoer', 
    templateUrl: './campinginvoer.component.html'
})
export class CampingInvoerComponent {
    InvoerCampingNaam = '';

    onCreateCamping() {
        console.log('Created a camping: ' + this.InvoerCampingNaam);
        this.InvoerCampingNaam = '';
    }
}
```

**camping.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-camping',
    templateUrl: './camping.component.html'
})
export class CampingComponent {
    @Input()
    campingList: string[] = [];
}
```

**camping.component.html:**

```
<u>
    <li *ngFor="let camping of campingList">{{ camping }}</li>
</u>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CampingComponent } from './camping.component';
import { CampingInvoerComponent } from './campinginvoer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, CampingComponent, CampingInvoerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 campings: string[] = ['De Karnemelkplaats', 'Tro Do Way', 'Camping Kohnenhof', 
 'Camping    Langewald', 'Camping La Fouly'];
  title: any[] = [];
}
```

**app.component.specs.ts:**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
});

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'oefenenmetangular'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('oefenenmetangular');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('oefenenmetangular 
    app is running!');
  });
});
```

**app.component.css:**

This one is empty

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-camping-invoer></app-camping-invoer>
<app-camping [campingList]="campings"></app-camping>
```

**The error I get is:**

Can't bind to 'ngModule' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ngtsc (-998002)
campinginvoer.component.ts(2,70): error occurs in the template of component CampingInvoerComponent.
Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'. ngtsc (2322)
campinginvoer.component.ts(2,70): error occurs in the template of component CampingInvoerComponent.
(property) CampingInvoerComponent.InvoerCampingNaam: string

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDzVo.jpg)

What is going wrong?

Thanks, Miranda

I tried to make a campinglist and a button to insert new campings to the list with angular.

I followed my book, but it's an older version than I'm working with. I get an error and it doesn't do what I want. Also my http:..localhost:4200 doesn't open.

Comment: Changing  [(ngModule)] to [(ngModel)] might fix it, but you might also need to use the @Input decorator on the property.

Comment: I found the problem. I typed Module instead of Model. Thnx.